# Расположение, размеры и фон DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

`DialogFragment`  вызывается `Fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "ggg");` данные для фрагмента берутся в xml файле. Имеется активити в котором на весь экран `SurfaceView` и в определенный момент вызывается `DialogFragment`. Так вот он появляется по середине экрана, а как можно самому задать 1) расположение 2) размеры 3) фоном установить изображение?

Как я понял размер DialogFragment лучше указывать  match_parent или wrap_content , а не в dp , так как разные устройства имеют своё ограничение для размера диалога.

Попытка разместить диалог :

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.gameoverfragment, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT);


        return(builder.setTitle("").setView(form).create());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Расположение (например, в нижнем правом углу)

```
getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT);
```

2) Размеры (например, во всю ширину экрана)

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams p = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
p.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(p);
```

3) Фон. Если вы про фон окна то достаточно добавить в корневой элемент разметки окна

```
 android:background="@android:color/green"
```

**UPD**

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.gameoverfragment, null);
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(form);
dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT);
  return dialog;
}
```

Comment: вписываю код из первого примера , говорит что getWindow null .  В вопросе добавил код куда я вписал ваш код. Мне наверняка надо что то объявить и инициализировать

Comment: Попробуйте `builder.getDialog....` или `builder.getWindow()`

Comment: Стойте я сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Обновил ответ. Как видите инфлэйт разметки, создание `Dialog`, отключение заголовка окна, установка `View`, установка расположения окна и возвращение созданного окна из метода

Comment: Вместо setRequestFeature  мне подходит requestWindowFeature.   http://s019.radikal.ru/i643/1701/9b/3aa80c7099f4t.jpg                в return ошибка, не возвращает диалог..

Comment: 1. Да, я не мог проверить код и написал на память, верно подмечено 2. Не надо вообще выполнять `create()` у диалога. Метод должен его возвращать. Поэтому возвращайте просто `dialog`.

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо. И поясните пожалуйста принципиальное отличие метода вызова диалога , который вы предложили и от того который был у меня . Это разные виды диалогов ?

Comment: `AlertDialog` используется для создания окна с заголовком, стандартным сообщением и тремя кнопка внизу. По вашему коду я заметил, что вы не используете ничего из этого

Comment: Только ставите кастомную разметку. Для этого `AlertDialog` болеп чем надо. Достаточно простой `Dialog`. Я сам делал как вы, просто понял что это неправильно. Вот и вам советую :) Удачного кодинга!